# Why does the stomp listener on_disconnected method get triggered multiple times for a single disconnect?

Tags: python, activemq-classic, stomp

I have a listener (inheriting from `stomp.ConnectionListener`) for a STOMP 1.2 connection. It's currently subscribing to 3 queues. Below are the connection and subscription codes.

When the ActiveMQ 5.16.2 server is shutdown, it looked like the listener's `on_disconnected` function is triggered multiple times, even though there was no reconnection attempt made in between.

Any idea why that would be? Does this have any correlation to the number of subscriptions?

Updated: Adding a minimal reproducible example as requested. Cannot include host, port or any credentials here.

`server.py`:

```
import stomp
from time import sleep

if __name__ == '__main__':
    conn = stomp.Connection12([(__host, __port)])
    conn.connect(__user, __password, wait=True)
    while(True):
        now = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")

        conn.send(destination=__topic_name1, body='topic1: test information 1 '+ now)
        print("sent topic 1")
        time.sleep(SLEEP_TIME)

        conn.send(destination=__topic_name2, body='topic2: test information 2 '+ now)
        print("sent topic 2")
        time.sleep(SLEEP_TIME)

        conn.send(destination=__topic_name3, body='topic3: test information 3 '+ now)
        print("sent topic 3")
        time.sleep(SLEEP_TIME)

        time.sleep(10)
    conn.disconnect()
```

`receiver.py`:

```
import stomp
from time import sleep

HEARTBEATS = 30000

class MyListener(stomp.ConnectionListener):

    def set_conn(self, conn):
        self._conn = conn

    def on_connected(self, frame):
        print(f"On connected: {frame}")

    def on_disconnected(self):
        print("disconnected")

    def on_message(self, frame):
        print(f"on message = {frame}")

class Connection():
    def __init__(self, listener):
        self._conn = stomp.Connection12([(HOST,PORT)], heartbeats=(HEARTBEATS, HEARTBEATS))
        self._conn.set_listener("My listener", listener)

    def connect_and_subscribe(self, destinations):
        for _id, dest in enumerate(destinations, 1):
            client_id = dest.strip(".01")
            self._conn.connect(USER, PASSWORD, wait=True,headers={"client-id": client_id})

            self._conn.subscribe(
                destination=dest, id=_id, ack="auto"
            )
            print(f"Subscribed to {dest}")

def main():
    listener = MyListener()
    conn = Connection(listener)
    listener.set_conn(conn)

    destinations = ["FirstTopic.01", "SecondTopic.01", "ThirdTopic.01", "FourthTopic.01"]
    conn.connect_and_subscribe(destinations)

    while True:
        sleep(5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I ctrl+c the ActiveMQ server only once. This is the output:

```
On connected: {cmd=CONNECTED,headers=[{'server': 'ActiveMQ/5.16.2', 'heart-beat': '30000,30000', 'session': 'FirstTopic', 'version': '1.2'}],body=}
Subsribed to FirstTopic.01
Subsribed to SecondTopic.01
Subsribed to ThirdTopic.01
Subsribed to FourthTopic.01
disconnected
disconnected
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "receiver.py", line 53, in <module>
    main()
  File "receiver.py", line 50, in main
    sleep(5)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

As you can see, the number of times `on_disconnected` is triggered does not match the number of destinations. I have also seen in trigger 4 times a couple times.

AMQ debug logs.

```
2021-07-26 16:04:22,776 [0.1:60474@61613] TRACE StompIO                        - Received:
STOMP
accept-version:1.2
login:admin
heart-beat:30000,30000
host:127.0.0.1
client-id:FirstTopic
passcode:*****


2021-07-26 16:04:22,778 [0.1:60474@61613] DEBUG StompInactivityMonitor         - Stomp Inactivity Monitor read check interval: 30000ms, write check interval: 30000ms
2021-07-26 16:04:22,781 [0.1:60474@61613] DEBUG ProtocolConverter              - Stomp Connect heartbeat conf RW[30000,30000]
2021-07-26 16:04:22,791 [0.1:60474@61613] TRACE StompIO                        - Sending:
CONNECTED
server:ActiveMQ/5.16.2
heart-beat:30000,30000
session:FirstTopic
version:1.2


2021-07-26 16:04:22,793 [0.1:60474@61613] TRACE StompIO                        - Received:
SUBSCRIBE
ack:auto
destination:FirstTopic.01
id:1


2021-07-26 16:04:22,793 [0.1:60474@61613] TRACE LegacyFrameTranslator          - New Composite Destination name: queue://FirstTopic.01
2021-07-26 16:04:22,806 [0.1:60474@61613] TRACE StompIO                        - Received:
STOMP
accept-version:1.2
login:admin
heart-beat:30000,30000
host:127.0.0.1
client-id:SecondTopic
passcode:*****


2021-07-26 16:04:22,806 [0.1:60474@61613] WARN  ProtocolConverter              - Exception occurred for client FirstTopic (tcp://127.0.0.1:60474) processing: STOMP -> org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.ProtocolException: Already c
onnected.
2021-07-26 16:04:22,807 [0.1:60474@61613] DEBUG ProtocolConverter              - Exception detail
org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.ProtocolException: Already connected.
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.ProtocolConverter.onStompConnect(ProtocolConverter.java:745)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.ProtocolConverter.onStompCommand(ProtocolConverter.java:254)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.StompTransportFilter.onCommand(StompTransportFilter.java:85)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportSupport.doConsume(TransportSupport.java:83)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:233)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:215)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-07-26 16:04:22,809 [0.1:60474@61613] TRACE ProtocolConverter              - Command that caused the error: STOMP
accept-version:1.2
login:admin
heart-beat:30000,30000
host:127.0.0.1
client-id:SecondTopic
passcode:*****

2021-07-26 16:04:22,809 [0.1:60474@61613] TRACE StompIO                        - Sending:
ERROR
content-type:text/plain
message:Already connected.

org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.ProtocolE...d.java:748)

2021-07-26 16:04:22,810 [0.1:60474@61613] TRACE StompIO                        - Received:
SUBSCRIBE
ack:auto
destination:SecondTopic.01
id:2


2021-07-26 16:04:22,810 [0.1:60474@61613] TRACE LegacyFrameTranslator          - New Composite Destination name: queue://SecondTopic.01
2021-07-26 16:04:22,814 [0.1:60474@61613] TRACE StompIO                        - Received:
STOMP
accept-version:1.2
login:admin
heart-beat:30000,30000
host:127.0.0.1
client-id:ThirdTopic
passcode:*****


2021-07-26 16:04:22,814 [0.1:60474@61613] WARN  ProtocolConverter              - Exception occurred for client FirstTopic (tcp://127.0.0.1:60474) processing: STOMP -> org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.ProtocolException: Already c
onnected.
2021-07-26 16:04:22,814 [0.1:60474@61613] DEBUG ProtocolConverter              - Exception detail
org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.ProtocolException: Already connected.
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.ProtocolConverter.onStompConnect(ProtocolConverter.java:745)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.ProtocolConverter.onStompCommand(ProtocolConverter.java:254)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.StompTransportFilter.onCommand(StompTransportFilter.java:85)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportSupport.doConsume(TransportSupport.java:83)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:233)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:215)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-07-26 16:04:22,814 [0.1:60474@61613] TRACE ProtocolConverter              - Command that caused the error: STOMP
accept-version:1.2
login:admin
heart-beat:30000,30000
host:127.0.0.1
client-id:ThirdTopic
passcode:*****


2021-07-26 16:04:22,815 [0.1:60474@61613] TRACE StompIO                        - Sending:
ERROR
content-type:text/plain
message:Already connected.

org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.ProtocolE...d.java:748)

2021-07-26 16:04:22,815 [0.1:60474@61613] TRACE StompIO                        - Received:
SUBSCRIBE
ack:auto
destination:ThirdTopic.01
id:3



2021-07-26 16:04:22,815 [0.1:60474@61613] TRACE LegacyFrameTranslator          - New Composite Destination name: queue://ThirdTopic.01
2021-07-26 16:04:22,818 [0.1:60474@61613] TRACE StompIO                        - Received:
STOMP
accept-version:1.2
login:admin
heart-beat:30000,30000
host:127.0.0.1
client-id:FourthTopic
passcode:*****


2021-07-26 16:04:22,818 [0.1:60474@61613] WARN  ProtocolConverter              - Exception occurred for client FirstTopic (tcp://127.0.0.1:60474) processing: STOMP -> org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.ProtocolException: Already c
onnected.
2021-07-26 16:04:22,818 [0.1:60474@61613] DEBUG ProtocolConverter              - Exception detail
org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.ProtocolException: Already connected.
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.ProtocolConverter.onStompConnect(ProtocolConverter.java:745)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.ProtocolConverter.onStompCommand(ProtocolConverter.java:254)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.StompTransportFilter.onCommand(StompTransportFilter.java:85)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportSupport.doConsume(TransportSupport.java:83)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:233)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:215)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-07-26 16:04:22,819 [0.1:60474@61613] TRACE ProtocolConverter              - Command that caused the error: STOMP
accept-version:1.2
login:admin
heart-beat:30000,30000
host:127.0.0.1
client-id:FourthTopic
passcode:*****


2021-07-26 16:04:22,819 [0.1:60474@61613] TRACE StompIO                        - Sending:
ERROR
content-type:text/plain
message:Already connected.

org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.ProtocolE...d.java:748)

2021-07-26 16:04:22,819 [0.1:60474@61613] TRACE StompIO                        - Received:
SUBSCRIBE
ack:auto
destination:FourthTopic.01
id:4


2021-07-26 16:04:22,819 [0.1:60474@61613] TRACE LegacyFrameTranslator          - New Composite Destination name: queue://FourthTopic.01
```

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Updated the question with the example

Comment: Can you activate STOMP trace logging on ActiveMQ and paste the logs here? You can find instructions on how to enable this on the [ActiveMQ documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/stomp.html) (see the "Debugging" section).

Comment: I see you're using the headers `subscription-type` and `durable-subscription-name`. These headers are used by ActiveMQ Artemis. However, the `server` header returned from the broker in the `CONNECTED` frame is `ActiveMQ/5.16.2` (i.e. *not* ActiveMQ Artemis). Can you clarify this mismatch?

Comment: 1. I added the debug logs.
2. I just copied those from somewhere. I wasn't aware that they are Artemis specific headers.
3. I am not sure why I keep getting the "already connected" errors here. Should I make a separate post for this?

Comment: Ignore no.3. It's because I am calling `self._conn.connect` multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the problem is that the `self._conn.connect` is called for each destination it's subscribed to. So I had to modify `connect_and_subscribe` to this.

```
    def connect_and_subscribe(self, destinations):
        **self._conn.connect(USER, PASSWORD, wait=True,headers={"client-id": "client-id"})**
        for _id, dest in enumerate(destinations, 1):
            self._conn.subscribe(
                destination=dest, id=_id, ack="auto"
            )
            print(f"Subscribed to {dest}")
```

Now, it disconnects only once.

```
Subscribed to FirstTopic.01
Subscribed to SecondTopic.01
Subscribed to ThirdTopic.01
Subscribed to FourthTopic.01
disconnected
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "receiver-correct.py", line 54, in <module>
    main()
  File "receiver-correct.py", line 51, in main
    sleep(5)
KeyboardInterrupt
```